# The old "look out" of Blender?

Tags: interface

Are there any possibilities to organize back the new Blender to the old ones? I mean I would use the old modifiers dropdown menu. I miss the old Principled BSDF and I still miss the old search tool in the node setups. Any help? Thank you!

Comment: No but 3.6 LTS is supported until June 2025. I don't really see the problem with the Principled BSDF and searching in version 4 though. You very quickly get used to it. Just click the down arrows against the sections on the Principled BSDF to expand them and Shift-A and start typing the name of the node or modifier you want to find which is faster than having to search through the menus for them.

Comment: the problem is I don't have the patience to get used to the new design and do this every time in every software etc when this happens